# Laravel 5.5 The page has expired due to inactivity

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, entrust

I used laravel 5.4 and [Zizaco/entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust).
 Today I upgrade my project to 
Laravel 5.5.
When I want to login in my project show me this error

> The page has expired due to inactivity.
>   Please refresh and try again.

I changed `SESSION_DRIVER=file` to `SESSION_DRIVER=array`
Laravel show me this error

> This cache store does not support tagging.

I search on google and find this
https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/issues/468
and this post tell me set `SESSION_DRIVER=array`

Comment: You should show us code that generates error

Comment: I updated my post...

Answer (score 2):

I think you forget to put `{!!csrf_fields()!!}` inside your login form. Just check your login form, If not just put this code in form.

```
<form action="" method="">
{!!csrf_fields()!!}
//your input fields
</form>
```